# MetaWidget for .NET Web Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Does anyone know if MetaWidget support .NET? If not, is there anything similar to MetaWidget for .NET web development?

Answer (score 1):

We have no immediate plans to add .NET support to Metawidget. However, Metawidget is Open Source, so if you'd like to contribute you'd be very welcome. Or you could [purchase a support pack](http://metawidget.org/support.php) and we'll do the work.

Alternatively, Metawidget supports several HTML 5 client-side technologies such as pure JavaScript, JQuery UI, JQuery Mobile and AngularJS. Any of these can be connected to a .NET back-end using REST-ful services.